# Map Reduce Completed but pig Job Failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I recently came across this scenario where a MapReduce job seems to be successful in RM where as the PIG script returned with an exit code 8 which refers to "Throwable thrown (an unexpected exception)"

Added the script as requested:

```
REGISTER '$LIB_LOCATION/*.jar'; 

-- set number of reducers to 200
SET default_parallel $REDUCERS;
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb 3072;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 6144;

SET mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx2560m;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts -Xmx5120m;
SET mapreduce.job.queuename dt_pat_merchant;

SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts -Xmx5120m;
SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb 6144;

-- load data from EAP data catalog using given ($ENV = PROD)
data = LOAD 'eap-$ENV://event'
-- using a custom function
USING com.XXXXXX.pig.DataDumpLoadFunc
('{"startDate": "$START_DATE", "endDate" : "$END_DATE", "timeType" : "$TIME_TYPE", "fileStreamType":"$FILESTREAM_TYPE", "attributes": { "all": "true" } }', '$MAPPING_XML_FILE_PATH');

-- filter out null context entity records
filtered = FILTER data BY (attributes#'context_id' IS NOT NULL);

-- group data by session id
session_groups = GROUP filtered BY attributes#'context_id';

-- flatten events
flattened_events = FOREACH session_groups GENERATE FLATTEN(filtered);

-- remove the output directory if exists
RMF $OUTPUT_PATH;

-- store results in specified output location
STORE flattened_events INTO '$OUTPUT_PATH' USING com.XXXX.data.catalog.pig.EventStoreFunc();
```

And I can see "ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. GC overhead limit exceeded" in the pig logs.(log below)

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. GC overhead limit exceeded

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter.values(FileSystemCounter.java:23)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.FileSystemCounterGroup.findCounter(FileSystemCounterGroup.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.FileSystemCounterGroup.findCounter(FileSystemCounterGroup.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.FileSystemCounterGroup.findCounter(FileSystemCounterGroup.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounters.findCounter(AbstractCounters.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:391)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getTaskReports(ClientServiceDelegate.java:451)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getTaskReports(YARNRunner.java:594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$3.run(Job.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$3.run(Job.java:543)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskReports(Job.java:543)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getTaskReports(HadoopShims.java:235)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.addMapReduceStatistics(MRJobStats.java:352)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:233)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:165)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:360)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:282)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1431)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1416)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1405)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:456)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:439)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:624)
```

Configuration in the pig script looks like below:

```
SET default_parallel 200;
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb 3072;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 6144;

SET mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx2560m;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts -Xmx5120m;
SET mapreduce.job.queuename dt_pat_merchant;

SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts -Xmx5120m;
SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb 6144;
```

Status of the Job in the RM of the Cluster says the job succeeded [can't post the image as my reputation is too low ;) ]

This issue occurs frequently and we have to restart the job the job successful.

Please let me know a fix for this.

PS: The cluster the job is running is one of the biggest in the world, so no worry with resources or the storage space I say.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add your pig script here?

I think, you get this error because the pig itself (not mappers and reducers) can't handle the output. 
If you use `DUMP` operation it your script, then try to limit the displayed dataset first. Let's assume, you have a `X` alias for your data. Try:

```
temp = LIMIT X 1;
DUMP temp;
```

Thus, you will see only one record and save some resources. You can do a `STORE` operation as well (see in pig manual how to do it).

Obviously, you can configure pig's heap size to be bigger, but pig's heap size is not *mapreduce.map* or *mapreduce.reduce*. Use `PIG_HEAPSIZE` environment variable to do that.

Comment: Added the script as requested, Please check!

Comment: May be your custom functions com.XXXXXX.pig.DataDumpLoadFunc and com.XXXX.data.catalog.pig.EventStoreFunc() use too much heap. Try to increase pig's heap using PIG_HEAPSIZE environment variable. See this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10166449/2877029

Comment: Increased the PIG_HEAPSIZE, seems to have fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

From [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html):

After a garbage collection, if the Java process is spending more than approximately 98% of its time doing garbage collection and if it is recovering less than 2% of the heap and has been doing so far the last 5 (compile time constant) consecutive garbage collections, then a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception for GC Overhead limit exceeded can be turned off with the command line flag -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

As said in docs, you can turn this exception off or increase heap size.

Comment: Heap for Mapper or reducer?? but mappers and reducers are successful as per the RM.

Comment: Error happened in client while getting counters, so increase heap for you pig client